# Image cannot be set with ImageSource.FromStream

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm having the wierdest problem. I try to set the Source property of an Image object on the constructor using Image.FromStream method and I'm not able to make ir work. It just does not display the image.

```
    public ImageRecognitionPage (Stream image)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        imgPhoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            return image;
        });

        _imagen = ReadFully(image);
    }
```

The stream is correct because I send _imagen to AWS Rekognition later and it works well. The thing is just that the image is not being showed.

I wasted too much time on this incredibly simple problem. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: check this please : ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image));

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it work. It happens that Source was not properly being set on the constructor. I moved the code to OnAppearing and that started to work.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(_imagen);
    imgPhoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });

    await Recognize(_imagen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
        byte[] buffer;
        long length = image.Length;
        buffer = new byte[length];
        image.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
        imgPhoto.Source= ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(buffer));
```